# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' Can't fetch json data

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Can someone help me to fix this problem. i can't fetch data from json using flutter http request because it got this **Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'** and want to load more data when scroll to bottom of screen. Can somebody help me please...

postData.dart file

```
class PostData extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostData({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostDataState createState() => _PostDataState();
}

class _PostDataState extends State<PostData> {
  List<String> getData = List();
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchFive();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        fetchFive();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Load Page"),
          toolbarHeight: 65,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[700],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: getData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(getData[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }

  fetch() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        getData.add(json.decode(response.body));
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  fetchFive() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fetch();
    }
  }
}
```

getData.dart file model json

```
class Users {
  final int no;
  final String nosiri;
  final String lokasi;
  final String status;
  final String pemilik;
  final String thumbnailurl;

  Users(
      {this.no,
      this.nosiri,
      this.lokasi,
      this.status,
      this.pemilik,
      this.thumbnailurl});

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Users(
      no: json['no'],
      nosiri: json['no_siri'],
      lokasi: json['lokasi'],
      status: json['status'],
      pemilik: json['pemilik'],
      thumbnailurl: json['thumbnailurl'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
List<Users> getData = [];
```

change

```
getData.add(json.decode(response.body));
```

to

```
getData.addAll(List<Users>.from(json.decode(response.body).map((x) => Users.fromJson(x))));
```

Comment: but for load data when scroll is not working. Data become duplicate so  many.. can't you tell why?

Comment: May be you are using add not addAll, and you fetch 5 time? Not sure that

Comment: i'm using addAll and yeah i just want to fetch only 5 data but it appear show all data and when i scroll down it fetch the duplicate data...Btw thanks

Comment: I see, try setState after you fetch data and I highly recommend you use [flutter_pagewise](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pagewise) in your case

Comment: So i need to change listview to pagewiselistview right?

Comment: Yes, This package will handle fetch data and update list when you scroll to the end, you only need to fill the pageFuture model.

Comment: alright i will try my best... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**As a response you are getting `List<Map>` and you're trying to store that in `List<String>`.Please change it to `List<dynamic>` or `List<Map>`**

```
   [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Post 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Post 3"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking your code your responce is `List<Map>` form and you declare `List<String>`. So you need to remove your `String` format from `List`.

```
List getData = List();
```

Then you need to convert your data into `List` like the below and then add it one by one in `getData`. And then you can add your data onto the `Text`.

```
ListTile(
  title: Text(getData[index]['title'].toString()),
),
```

And your `fetch()` method be like

```
  fetch() async {
    final response = await http
        .get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var i in data) {
          getData.add(i);
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```